# transparent png in internet explorer 6

Tags: png, internet-explorer-6, compatibility

I want to make a website ie 6 compatible. I have included two PNG files (PNG-8) with `<img src>` tag. When I open the website with IE6, the pictures appears for a short moment and disappears again. How can I fix that without any javascript or other additional files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If adding JS is really not an option, you can try using the following filter:

```
img {
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(...);
}
```

I would, however, not recommend this... the JS methods are generally better.

Comment: I tried the filter, nothing happened :/ You are right.. I will do it with JS

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that without JavaScript or additional files.
IE6 does not support natively transparent PNG.

Here is a fix: http://www.twinhelix.com/css/iepngfix/

Answer (score 1):

ie6 does support transparency in 8bit, just not 32bit that most people use. and the support is not 100%, partial transparency will show as transparent, but the fact remains that you can get transparency in ie6.

you could create a gif specifically for ie6 and serve it up via conditional comments...that sounds optimal for what you are doing.
there are also a number of JavaScript and/or HTC solutions